# Vuejs: filter not working properly in my code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my vue js code below i have questions came from API with their categories all saved in questions array, what i want to achieve is when any of those categories clicked it should filter the questions that related to those categories only, but in my code it shows only single question with its category... like it's not showing all related questions with that clicked category .. any help please?

```js
  selectedAnswer(index) {
      this.selectedIndex = index;
      this.questions = this.questions.filter((question) =>
        question.categories.includes(index)
      );
      console.log(index);
    },
```

Comment: I don't know what you wanna do, be clear.

Comment: Show questions array and how do you want to filter that array. What is the filter criteria?

Comment: i have questions came from API with their categories all saved in questions array, what i want to achieve is when any of those categories clicked it should filter the questions that related to those categories only, in my code it shows only single question with its category... like it's not showing all related questions with that clicked category

Comment: It is hard to answer if I don't know the questions array. It would be helpful if you can show some demo code. You could use codesandbox if you want. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I try to understand your code, you need a primitive type(string, number, boolean) to filter out of your array. Otherwise, you can also try iterate inside of your filter since you comparing the objects.

```
    selectedAnswer(index) {
      this.selectedIndex = index;
      this.questions = this.questions.filter((question) =>
        question.categories.some((cat) => cat._id === index)
      );
    },
```

Note that 'index' is selected id of category.